# Draw on the screen without showing the color, and save the image

Tags: android

I need to draw on the screen, and capture it and show in another activity, but i don't need to show the paint color that it's drawing i.e only the fingers will be moving and no one will be able to see what it's drawing.

Have no idea how to progress in this case.
I have done draw like this, but this is normal and you see what some one is drawing:

```
    class SignatureView extends View {

      private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;

      private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;

      private Paint paint = new Paint();
      private Path path = new Path();

      private float lastTouchX;
      private float lastTouchY;
      private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

      public SignatureView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
      }

      public void clear() {


        path.reset();
        AddView();

        invalidate();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;
            return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);

            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
              float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
              float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
              expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
              path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
            }

            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;

          default:
            debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }

        invalidate(
            (int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
            (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
            (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
            (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
      }

      private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
          dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
          dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }
        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
          dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
          dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
      }


      private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {

        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
      }
    }
```

even tried setting the paint alpha to 0. but no use it sets the transparent image.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following change

```
paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```